# MySQL query with IN clause loses performance

Tags: mysql

I have a table to store data from csv files. It is a large table (over 40 million rows). This is its structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `imported_lines` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `day` date NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `origin_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` time(3) NOT NULL,
  `main_index` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `transaction_index` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `data` varchar(4096) NOT NULL,
  `error` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `expressions_applied` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `count_records` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `client_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `receive_date` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`client_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uq` (`client_id`,`name`,`origin_id`,`receive_date`),
  KEY `dh` (`day`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (`client_id`) PARTITIONS 15 */
```

When I perform a SELECT with one day filter, it returns data very quick (0.4 s). But, as I increase date range, it becomes slow, until gets a timeout error.

This is the query:

```
SELECT origin_id, error, main_index, transaction_index, 
expressions_applied, name, day,    
COUNT(id) AS total, SUM(count_records) AS sum_records
FROM imported_lines FORCE INDEX (dh)
WHERE client_id = 1
AND day >= '2017-07-02' AND day <= '2017-07-03'  
AND name IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3', ...)  
GROUP BY origin_id, error, main_index, transaction_index, expressions_applied, name, day;
```

I think the IN clause may be losing performance. I also tried to add `uq` index to this query, which gave a little gain (`FORCE INDEX (dh, uq)`). 
Plus, I tried to `INNER JOIN (SELECT name FROM providers WHERE id = 2) prov ON prov.name = il.name` but doesn't result in a quicker query as well.

**EDIT**
EXPLAINing the query

```
id - 1
select_type - SIMPLE
table - imported_lines
type - range
possible_keys - uq, dh
key - dh
key_len - 261
ref - NULL
rows - 297988
extra - Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Any suggestions what it should do?

Comment: Not releated to this query, but the primary key should just be `id`.

Comment: Show the output of `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Consider storing dates and times (and microseconds) as a single entity

Comment: Adding `client_id` to the `dh` key could help. Also, yes, `IN` tends to be rather inefficient; I would not be surprised if removing name from `dh` has little to no effect on the query speed.

Comment: @Uueerdo I added `client_id` to `dh` index. But I forgot to mention that `client_id` is a `PARTITION` column. Wouldn't that be redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a few changes, adding a new index with multiple columns (as suggested by @Uueerdo) and rewritten query as another user suggested too (but he deleted his answer).

I ran a few `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS` with queries, tested with `SQL_NO_CACHE` in order to guarantee it wouldn't use cache and searching data for **one whole month** now takes 1.8s.

It's so much faster!
This is what I did:

```
ALTER TABLE `imported_lines` DROP INDEX dh;
ALTER TABLE `imported_lines` ADD INDEX dhc (`day`, `name`, `client_id`);
```

Query:

```
SELECT origin_id, error, main_index, transaction_index, 
expressions_applied, name, day,    
COUNT(id) AS total, SUM(count_records) AS sum_records
FROM imported_lines il
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id FROM imported_lines
    WHERE client_id = 1 
    AND day >= '2017-07-01' AND day <= '2017-07-31'  
    AND name IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3', ...)  
) AS il_filter
ON il_filter.id = il.id
WHERE il.client_id = 1
GROUP BY origin_id, error, main_index, transaction_index, expressions_applied, name, day;
```

I realized using `INNER JOIN`, `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS` it began to use index. Also with `WHERE il.client_id = 1`, query reduces the number of partitions to look up.

Thanks for your help!